# SEO: why this site won't index?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

I recently built a one-page-site, All main pages are loaded via ajax, so they exist as standalone too versions as well in HTML format  through jQuery, only pages' content is loaded in the one-page-site.

I have created a sitemap and submitted all these things to Google Webmaster Tools, which tells me that everything is fine and pages are indexed and not blocked

I also posted the site URL in some specific forums where people talk about main product (Chirofol); a Facebook page is also to be released soon

Despite all these things, when I type "chirofol" on Google, the site is not even in the first three or four pages, and this is simply driving me mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your website is indexed. 
It takes time for a website to rank against some specific keyword. You need put some efforts for generating back-linkings to the website. It will take round 2 months for a website to appear in ttop 3 pages against a keywords like Chirofol
Site: